# WCF InstanceContextMode.Multiple issues

Tags: wcf, concurrency

So I'm hosting WCF service in a WinForms application.  I have the following

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, 
         InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Test : ITest
{
    public string TestIt(string input)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I'm using Named Pipes and have two instances of another application that act as clients to the above WCF service (running in a WinForms application).  I thought based on the ConcurrencyMode setting of Multiple that when Client1 calls the Test Service, Client2 doesn't have to wait till the first call is complete.  However, when Client1 calls TestIt, Client2 blocks until the call from Client1 is complete!?!?!  Shouldn't it make a new instance each time based on the above settings?

Also, is the best way to keep a WinForms application that is hosting a WCF service responsive is by running the WCF service on a separate thread?

NOTE: Setting [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)] on the Test class does not alleviate the problem.  The service still only responds to one request at a time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext.aspx

to false.  By default, if there is a synchronization context when service.Open() happens, WCF will pick it up and use it.  But if you don't want that feature, this flag is how to turn it off.

Comment: Setting [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)] on the Test class does not alleviate the problem. The service still only responds to one request at a time.

Comment: i have the same problem. why was this answer accepted if this is not the solution to your problem? did you solve it another way?

Comment: See his comment on his own answer below - this was in fact the solution.

Answer (score 4):

After digging into this a bit more the only way I was able to get this to work properly was to start the ServiceHost on a separate thread in the WinForms application.  If you don't do that setting the ConcurrencyMode and InstanceContextMode attributes does nothing.

Comment: Brian's answer is correct here AKoran.  To stop you from running into thread synchronization issues, by default if you use WCF in a winform, it will synchronise on the winform.  Set UseSynchronizationContext=false and you will get WCF to make a thread for you.

Comment: I guess I must be doing something else wrong then because setting these attributes still blocks the entire WinForm app:

    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]

Comment: Ahh, sometimes when you stare and something too long you lose it...I was using CallBackBehavior instead of ServiceBehavior.  You are correct.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Feel free to give me a check mark and mark my answer as correct then :)

Comment: I tried already! Apparently I don't have enough "reputation" to check or uncheck marks.  When/If I ever get there I'll be sure to come back and give you a mark!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My class that implemented Callback also contained methods for wcf client, so when I was calling some method from remote service and service was calling Callback method, I was creating a deadlock.

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class AppContext : ICustomerOrderCallback
{
    //WCF Proxy client
    private CustomerOrderClient _client = null;

    public AppContext()
    {
        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this); 
        _client = new CustomerOrderClient(context);
        _client.Subscribe();  //Remote method for subscribing callback
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        //Calling Remote method 
        _client.SendMessage(message);
    }

    //....code

    //callback method
    public void OnMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        //.....code
    }
}
```

So I created a separate class for callback, added attribute CallBehavior to it and everything worked OK.

```
public class AppContext
{
    private CustomerOrderClient _client = null;

    private MyCallbackClass _myCallback = null;
    public AppContext()
    {
        _myCallback = new MyCallbackClass();
        InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(_myCallback); 
        _client = new CustomerOrderClient(context);
        _client.Subscribe();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        _client.SendMessage(message);
    }
}

[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyCallbackClass : ICustomerOrderCallback
{
    public void OnMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        //.....code
    }
}
```