# What is the use of UseSynchronizationContext in WCF

Tags: wcf

i am very new in WCF. so often gaze for wcf code & article. after viewing many code i often stuck for very basic things and got no elaborate discussion for the below question. so here are my few basic question....and looking for details discussion with sample situation and with sample code.

what is the meaning of UseSynchronizationContext=false 
when one should turn on UseSynchronizationContext=true 
or when one should go for UseSynchronizationContext=false ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its to do with whether, by default, WCF will attempt to use an existing thread synchronization context or not. There is an interesting question related to this here:-

[WCF InstanceContextMode.Multiple issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592458/wcf-instancecontextmode-multiple-issues)

Also a codeproject posting about synchronizationcontext here:-

[Understanding SynchronizationContext (Part I)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I)

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext.aspx) it looks like the default for this is true.